# 'Se' in 'Se tardó el tren por el mal clima'

Tags: gramática, reflexivos, voz-pasiva

### Question

What is the function of 'se' in "Se tardó el tren por el mal clima"?

The statement itself may be wrong, but if it is correct, which one is the function of 'se'?

1. Passive (The tren was delayed by the bad weather)
2. Reflexive (Like 'se rompió el tren')

Comment: @guifa thanks for the comment and indicating intransitive/pronominal. Researched a bit and it looks 'tardar' does not have a transitive verb function to mean 'delay [sthg]'. So it should be reflexive (similar to retrasarse) meaning "The train took so long due to the bad weather", I suppose. Anyway, thanks for providing a clue.

Comment: To be reflexive, a verb has to be able to take a direct or indirect object and have one of those objects be the same as the subject.  *tardarse* is not reflexive because it's not transitive, it just requires the pronouns (all reflexive verbs are pronominals, but not all pronominals are reflexive).  In the pronominal form it means "it took *too* long".

Comment: @guifa, thanks for another clue. I still need to spend more time on 'se' which is pronominal but reflexive. Will dig into se in 'tardarse'.

Comment: Is it possible it's just a commonly accepted, but still incorrect, way of speaking? I know plenty of native speakers who use reflexive tense as often as they possibly can. Heaven knows we don't always speak the Queen's English around here, either ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use *se* here:

> se tardó el tren por el mal clima.
>
> el tren se tardó por el mal clima.

*se* works as a reflexive. If you want to skip it, then write:

> el tren tardó por el mal clima.

However saying *tardó el tren por el mal clima* may be portrayed as a question: *¿tardó el tren por el mal clima?* To avoid that, we use *se* to put it in affirmative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wonder if it is actually reflexive as having seen a comment it is not...

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is wrong. `Tardar` is not a reflexive verb (is not even transitive). If you were using passive you would be saying something like

> El tren **fue retrasado** / Fue cancelado, etc.

(Actually is difficult to use passive with `tardar`, you need to use `retrasar` instead)

Comment: Actually, the DRAE lists *tardar* as either *intransitivo* or *pronominal* for the sense of taking too long (but not in the sense of taking or lasting some amount of time)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tardar specifies an example "Se tardaron tanto en llegar al cine que se perdieron la película." for 'tardarse'. So I believe it can be reflexive?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this *se* is the way the verb *tardar* is used. In Spain the verb *tardar* is intransitive, so here we would say "**Se retrasó el tren por el mal clima**" but there are other countries where *tardar* is used like *retrasar* (reflexively).

So, your question depends mostly of the country where you are speaking. I can tell for Spain, I don't know for sure about other countries.

Answer (score -1):

PLEASE, PLEASE!

"se" doesn't work there... ever

it is a very common mistake in lower level common dialogue

**el tren tardó por el mal clima**

clima mal, even if forcedly correct, sounds like a hammer in your ears

by the way, sorry for my English, but is only my 4th language... hope to help

Comment: When it's used to mean *emplear demasiado tiempo* the *se* is perfectly expected.

Comment: *se* works and depends on the context you're using it